# Does the terminology in PostgreSQL match MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

MySQL seems to use words like users and tables, whereas PostgreSQL seems to use words like users, schemas and relations. Are they equivalent? Is there a quick guide to which words in MySQL match PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a table comparing MySQL's terminology to PostgreSQL's. Each row contains equivalent terminology.

```
+----------------------+-----------------------+
|        MySQL         |      PostgreSQL       |
+----------------------+-----------------------+
| user                 | login role (user)     |
| table                | relation (or table)   |
| database             | schema                |
| (N/A)                | database              |
| instance             | cluster               |
+----------------------+-----------------------+
```

In MySQL, the full absolute name of a table is `database.table`, whereas in PostgreSQL, the full name is `database.schema.table`.

<sub>*When it comes to roles in PostgreSQL, PostgreSQL used to distinguish between users and groups, but in newer versions of PostgreSQL there is only one concept: a role. See this question: [in PostgreSQL, what is the difference between user and role?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27709456/247696)</sub>

Comment: A MySQL database corresponds to a PostgreSQL schema. There is no equivalent to a PostgreSQL database in MySQL. I'll edit the answer accorsingly.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks, that's really helpful, I'm only starting PostgreSQL myself. For me, a "schema" in PostgreSQL simply seems like a namespace for relations, and a database is simply a namespace for schemas. What is so distinctive about a database is PostgreSQL that makes you confident that MySQL does not have the equivalent? Aren't databases and schemas in PostgreSQL just namespaces at different levels?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I would like to add back "database (or schema)" (instead of just "database") in the MySQL column. MySQL documentation does refer to schemas ([example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-default-schema.html)), and in MySQL, databases and schemas are basically the same thing.

Comment: In my opinion, the thing that makes a database in PostgreSQL very different from a schema is that it is *not* a namespace, but that it provides a border. You cannot `SELECT` from a different database. That is quite a difference, and important if you want to separate different applications. Hence I also see your remark about the "full name" in your answer as not very relevant, but I cannot contradict it either. And anyhow, it's your answer even though I messed with it.