# PostgreSQL: drop user Or drop role?

Tags: postgresql

I created a read only user in PostgreSQL using the command line by:

```
CREATE USER xyz WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'xxx';
GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE mydb TO xyz;
```

In order to delete this user, what's the difference between

```
DROP USER xyz;
```

and

```
DROP ROLE xyz;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a user and a role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709456/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-and-a-role)

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropuser.html):

> `DROP USER` is simply an alternate spelling of `DROP ROLE`.

Comment: The difference between user and role is that the user already has login option, with the role you can manipulate if it has login or nologin option.